# Meaning of "Gets you by"?

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

What's the meaning of the phrasal verb "**gets you by**" in the following context?

> My father was a painter so I was encouraged to take a sketchbook
> everywhere. Cameras are perishable but I still have tonnes of
> sketchbooks from all the trips I've ever been on. It gets you by when
> you don't know what to give people as a gift; drawings are good
> souvenirs.

[[Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/my-life-travel-jane-birkin-singer-and-actress-2309007.html)]

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Is “gets you by” the phrasal verb, or is there another one? $10,000 a month gets you by?  A $50 tip will get you by the doorman?

Comment: "The mugger gets you by surprise." - the words "gets you by" can be used in a number of ways.

Comment: The cat gets you by the neck. The cops get you by the lake. The book gets you by the soul.

Comment: ["get by"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20by) is a phrasal verb, but it's intransitive so can't take "you" as an object. If that's what you're talking about. Can you provide an example sentence?

Comment: Here's the context https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/my-life-travel-jane-birkin-singer-and-actress-2309007.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard this phrase used like this, but the context makes the meaning clear to me. The drawings happen to be useful because they can be used as a gift if you don't have any other ideas.

"It gets you by" has a normal usage similar to, "an acceptable, but not exceptional result" - You've encountered an obstacle or challenge, and you were able to move past it, but not in any particular exceptional way.

So, in this context, the drawings become useful in the case where your challenge is trying to find someone a gift. Again, it's kind of an unusual usage of the phrase.